# SQL 13 months transaction and quantity data extract broken down per month

Tags: sql, delphi, dbisam

I was reading through a couple of older posts and tried to apply the same logic to my question, I need to extract 13 months of data broken down per month, I would also like to apply the data to relevant headers... any suggestions. Please see code below and error received.

```sql
SELECT ST.TXDATE, ST.CODE, ST.QUANTITY    
FROM StocTran ST
WHERE ST.TXDATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
ORDER BY ST.TXDATE
```

> ERROR: [Elevate Software][DBISAM] DBISAM Engine Error # 11949 SQL 
>   parsing error - Expected end of statement but instead found ( in 
>   SELECT SQL statement at line 3, column 27 Error Code: 11949

Comment: can you link some of the older posts?

Comment: `DATEADD` is a function in MS's TransactSQL for Sql Server.  Are you sure DBIsam supports `DATEADD`?

Comment: How do you intend to cope with the fact that one of the months will be there twice?

Comment: @DanBracuk:  That makes no difference if you express the WHERE clause as a range of dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DATEADD is a function in MS's TransactSQL for Sql Server. I do not know that DBIsam supports it, and it is not listed in DBIsam's list of supported functions here:

https://www.elevatesoft.com/manual?action=viewtopic&id=dbisam4&product=delphi&version=7&topic=functions

Generally, date functions are not portable across different SQL engines, and from that list, one possibility might be to use  the `EXTRACT` function instead:

> The EXTRACT function returns a specific value from a date, time, or timestamp value. The syntax is as follows:

```
EXTRACT(extract_value
        FROM column_reference or expression)
EXTRACT(extract_value,
        column_reference or expression)
```

> Use EXTRACT to return the year, month, week, day of week, day, hours, minutes, seconds, or milliseconds from a date, time, or timestamp column. EXTRACT returns the value for the specified element as an integer.
>
> The extract_value parameter may contain any one of the specifiers:
>   YEAR
>   MONTH
>   WEEK
>   DAYOFWEEK
>   DAYOFYEAR
>   DAY
>   HOUR
>   MINUTE
>   SECOND
>   MSECOND

Even if you are in a hurry, I strngly recommend that you study that page carefully.

**UPDATE**: From googling `dbisam dateadd` it looks like Elevate don't have a good answer for an equivalent to `DATEADD`.  One of the hits is this thread:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic173627-169-1.aspx

which suggested an alternative way to do it using Delphi's built-in date functions (like `IncMonth` which I suggested you use in an answer to another q.  Basically, you would calculate the start- and end-dates of a range of dates, then convert them to strings to construct a WHERE clause with a column date (from your db) which is equal to or greater than the start date and less or equal to the end date.

Comment: do you have any suggestions how to create a variable report using this data extract function, e.g.: EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SaleDate) AS MonthNo - 1, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SaleDate) AS MonthNo -2 ... and so forth?

Comment: No, because I don't have a copy of DBIsam to test it on.  But basically it would involve constructing a WHERE clause equivalent to your DATEADD one.  The people to ask about this are DBIsam's publishers, Elevate Software.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, but maybe I should not try and re-invent the wheel and rather maniplulate the code I already have to give me an additional month of data. Is there anyway I can mail you some code that you could look at, I dont want to post all that code in the forum?